# How to Use df.to_sql and Export Data With Two Indexes to a Table in SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a data frame with two indexes, and I am trying to export it to a SQL Server table.  Here is the code that I am using.

```
grouped_and_summed.to_sql(x, engine, if_exists='append', index=True, index_label=None)
```

The 'x' variable is the name of the table and the 'engine' variable comes form here.

```
engine = "mssql+pyodbc://MyServerName/MyTableName?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"
```

When I have just one index, and export the results to a SQL Server table, everything works fine.  When I have two indexes and export the results to a CSV, everything works just fine.  I have problems exporting a DF with two indexes to a SQL Server table.  I read through the documentation here.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

The documentation says 'A sequence should be given if the DataFrame uses MultiIndex'.  I'm not sure what that means.  I'm not sure how to to handle that in Python code.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: it would be helpful if you add the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `index_label=['MultiIndex1 name', 'MultiIndex2 name']`